How do you check a collection of values into a column which has multiple selection?
Employees is a sharepoint list containing 2 columns:
Employee (Person)
Teams (lookup field in the Teams list)
Teams is a sharepoint list containing 2 columns:
Title (Text)
Head of team (Person)
At the moment, I have a gallery which results is based on the following query:
Filter(Employees, "Project Management" in Teams.Value Or "Cyber" in Teams.Value)

This works.
But I would like to actually retreive all employees filtering on Teams.Value with the result of another filter, which is retrieving all titles (.Title) from the currently logged in user from the 2nd table Teams.
I tried something like:
Filter(Employees, Filter([@Teams], 'Head of team'.Email in User().Email).Title in Teams.Value)

But that doesn't work, with error message on
Teams.Value
->  PowerApps can't convert this table to a text....
Any idea?
Thanks for reading!

Temporary solved the problem with an ugly solution which works only on the first 5 teams the employee is the head of. Should he have more than 5 teams under his/her responsibility they will be missed.
Filter(Employees, Index(Filter([@Teams], 'Head of team'.Email in User().Email),1).Title in Teams.Value
Or
Index(Filter([@Teams], 'Head of team'.Email in User().Email),2).Title in Teams.Value
Or
Index(Filter([@Teams], 'Head of team'.Email in User().Email),3).Title in Teams.Value
Or
Index(Filter([@Teams], 'Head of team'.Email in User().Email),4).Title in Teams.Value
Or
Index(Filter([@Teams], 'Head of team'.Email in User().Email),5).Title in Teams.Value
) 

Edit 1:
A more elegant version, although triggering some delegation warning, is to have a piece in the start in the start screen on the OnStart property:
   // Collect teams where the current user is the 'Head of team'
   ClearCollect(
        UserTeams,
        Filter(
            Teams,
            'Head of team'.Email = User().Email
        ) );

Then on the gallery itself, using countif on the table UserTeams we created earlier:
Filter(
    Employees,
    CountIf(
        'Member Of',
        Value in UserTeams.Title
    ) > 0
)

